# Decompiling PYC files for python 3.9.2

Tags: python, decompiler, deobfuscation, pyc

Currently, I have a PYC file for the 3.9.2 version of python (P.S: This applies to all versions 3.9 and above).
I'm trying to decompile the PYC file but it is showing an error as uncompyle6 (or rather, the newer version, decompyle3) is not compatible with Python versions 3.9 and above.


I was wondering if there are any alternative methods that can be used rather than decompyle3 to get the source of PYC files, or maybe a hacky fix.

P.S. I did already try to pip install decompyle3 but it says

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for decompyle3
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sadly enough, it's currently impossible.
Decompile 3 has the latest pyc to py methods (decompilation),
but it hasn't updated for python 3.9 yet as that update takes a very long time to create.
And it will most likely never happen for 3.9 (the developer of decompyle3 said that he is focusing more on his main job and that he doesn't have time to create this update as the 3.9 python update really changed the workflow, so it will be very hard and time-consuming).

So for now, the only solution is to wait, but if you want to speed things up, you can always sponsor the creator of decompile 3 (https://github.com/sponsors/rocky) (as he said that if you would get enough money to work more on this project, he will)

Edit:
I have recently found out that there is an alternative
I haven't used it myself, but its meant to decompile the compiled
python file (.pyc) back to humanly readable code (.py). For any python version!
You can check it out here: https://github.com/zrax/pycdc

Answer (score 5):

You need to pip install decompyle3 from the github link because its not on PyPI:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/rocky/python-decompile3
```

Comment: Hey @SuperStormer, when I type uncompyle6 it has an error `KeyError: '3.9.2'`

Comment: This installs `decompyle3`

Comment: I meant decompyle3, sorry for saying the wrong thing

Comment: Hmmm, decompyle3 might not have 3.9 support yet.

Comment: Tested 1 min. ago, decompyle3 works for the latest Python.

Comment: I get this: `$> decompyle3`
`Error: decompyle3 can decompile only bytecode from Python 3.7 to 3.8.
        You have version: 3.9.6.`

Answer (score 2):

Even if decompilation is not correct a had some success on decompiling Python 3.9 with [Decompyle++](https://github.com/zrax/pycdc)

A package that ships with Decompyle++ binaries can be installed with the following:

```
pip install pydumpck
```

Then on Windows can be executed directly, for example:

```
C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pydumpck\pyc_checker\lib_pycdc\pycdc.exe olds.pyc
```

This will fix the long path to run issue:
`set path=%path%;C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pydumpck\pyc_checker\lib_pycdc`

You may append `>olds.py` to the line above to write the output in a file.

Note: Adding `1>&2` to also have strerr output in the file is kinda useless.
It doesn't merges stdout and strerr lines in the order they are outputed.
*Instead it combines all strerr lines and adds them at the begin or end of stdout.*

I haven't found a solution to this.
*Hmm maybe `>&` could help out but I couldn't tested that yet.*

Well that will decompile all files in a path:

```
for %i in (*.pyc) do C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pydumpck\pyc_checker\lib_pycdc\pycdc.exe %i >%~ni.py
```

Comment: Heads up, pip package "pydc" is not related to Python decompilation. Though it looks like "pydumpck" ships with pre-built Decompyle++ binaries, the repo itself does not https://github.com/zrax/pycdc

Comment: It worked perfectly my friend, I was very grateful I had lost my code for not using the repository