# Python version 3.9+ is cannot be decompiled?

Tags: usb, driver, autorun

I have an exe produced with pyinstaller. this much I converted it to pyc format using the pyinstxtractor tool, then I found my main file among the extracted files. And uncompyle6 and decompile3 it I tried to decompile with the tools, but I learned that these tools support up to 3.8 at most. What should I do at this point, how can I access the source code of this exe. I can read a human-readable, disassembled version of pyc using a tool called pyc2bytecode, but is that all? What can I do to decompile python's compiled code for 3.9 or 3.10 back to source code?
I was wondering if there is a current solution to this problem...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decompiling PYC files for python 3.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66550211/decompiling-pyc-files-for-python-3-9-2)

Comment: https://github.com/zrax/pycdc this link is the recommended project at the last point, but it still doesn't work. yes, it decompiles the exe to a certain extent, but it does not provide full support for 3.9 and 3.10. Now python 3.11 is out and there is still no activity. For now I'm just waiting as I'm not crazy enough to build a python decompiler on my own

Answer (score 0):

The uncompyle6 highest version currently supported is python 3.8,if you need support python 3.9 and you need to make your self tool.

You can read this doc and use dis of python moulde：https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html?highlight=dis#module-dis